# Splash Screen between Activities in android

Tags: android, splash-screen

I Am new to android. I am doing project for wifi communication between server and client. i want to display the message in server whenever server receives the message from client. I am maintaining thread in server for accepting connection. i want to display the sum details in the first page. if any message from client i want to display it as well and i want to show that message continuously and main details page. so i planned to use splash screen whenever message comes another activity will be splashed and again main page will be shown. now how can i splash the message screen and main screen continuously??? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how you're implementation is. However i would suggest you not to create a new activity every time you receive a message from the server which is slow and doesn't look very natural in UI. You may just use a [dialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html%E2%80%8E) to display your server message and then close your DialogeFragment window dynamically whenever desired.

Finally, if you insist on creating new activities when a message is recieved you may use [intents](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html%E2%80%8E). You may close current activity using `finish()` method whenever necessary.

PS: Do not forget to have a look on [android notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/%E2%80%8E) which might be useful for your project.

Comment: If you need to show the message for many times, then you should not destroy your view. You will need to show/hide it(check fragment lifecycle in android doc). However I don't know what kind of notification is suitable for your case. A simple Toast might suffice.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to answer your question.Up to 3 seconds this splash screen will appear with a      Textview.

```
  private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);

    TextView splashtxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.splashtextview);




    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){


        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Creating an Intent to start another activity
             * After starting MainpageActivity i am closing this (SplashscreenActivity) 
             * Activity.
             */             
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashscreenActivity.this,MainpageActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }

    },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```